# How to revoke refresh token for Azure AD B2C in React Native?

Tags: azure, react-native, azure-ad-b2c

I have the refresh token expiry on B2C set to the minimum and I left my account logged in but inactive for the past couple days. Now, I'm receiving logs showing the mobile application is trying to get a new access token using the expired refresh token but I'm catching an error: "time out".

Correct me if I'm wrong but from what I understand, refresh tokens don't expire and I need to manually revoke them then send the user back to log in screen? How do I revoke the refresh token on client side?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to revoke the refresh token, you can use power shell: [Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/users-revoke-access#azure-active-directory-environment),

or AAD Graph API : `POST https://graph.windows.net/{tenant id}/me/invalidateAllRefreshTokens?api-version=1.6 HTTP/1.1`.